# intel x86 emulator accelerator not compatible with linux

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to use intel x86 emulator accelerator for better performance as other emulator dies out while loading because of low configuration of machine. I am using Linux Mint 32 bit. Is there any way I can enable it and use it.

Here is a screenshot of the issue: [image: http://tinypic.com/r/1eunwh/5]

Comment: It would seem that in order to enable it, you must first rewrite whatever it has that is incompatible with Linux in order to make it compatible (which doesn't seem likely).

Comment: It's strange, because Intel has an article on how to use their HAXM accelerator with Linux: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can't use this extension, but you can run the Intel avd images with qemu and KVM. You'll notice a totally different emualator experience - compared to the ARM emulation.

So basically you only need to run `emulator -avd <avd_name> -qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm` at a shell. More details here: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#vm-linux

Notice that your CPU needs to support some virtualization technologies. More about kvm installation here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Finally I have decided to use my real android phone as a testing device. Thanks for your suggestion by the way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fast emulator alternative named [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com/) for android which run on all platforms including Linux, mac OS, and windows.
It also support full mobile device emulation, for example you can download Xperia Z image file and test your application on that Virtual machine. Also you have to install Virtualbox on your computer.

have fun.

Comment: Heads up: Not free for commercial use.